# Click button until button disappears from webPage

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have web page in which it displays only 10 items if there are more then 10 items on the page then show more button displays, so need to click on show more button to see more then 10 items.

Problem is when I click on show more button it will display 10 more item and then again i have to click show more button to see next 10 more item and once all items are displayed on the page then show more button disappears from page.
Here I want to click show more button until all the items are displayed

How to achieve this using Selenium + Web driver?

Comment: This is more something with your SQL request. Not with selenium's action. I mean the 1st show only display the 10 first items, and each time you click on "more" you'll add 10 to the current item listed and it will refresh the page with the new SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Until "show more" button present keep clicking on that link in loop.

```
while(isElementPresent(By.linkText("Show more"))) {
   driver.findElement(By.linkText("Show more")).click();
   Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

Check [here for isElemenetPresent](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.com/2012/07/iselementpresent.html)() methods implimentation.

P.S : For safety break the loop after reaching some max limit.

Comment: You probably want a short `Thread.sleep()` in that loop so you don't click too fast. Maybe 50ms or something?